# How to write custom validation rule in controller Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have default validation rule in controller Laravel:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'code' => 'required|string|min:3|max:4',
            'timezone' => 'required|numeric',
            'country' => 'required|integer',
            'agreement' => 'accepted'
        ]);
```

I tried this, but dont know how to transfer some parameters inside function:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('phone_unique', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
            return substr($value, 0, 3) == '+44';
        });
    }
```

How can I extent this validation by my own rule? For example I need to validate concatination of inputs:

```
$phone = $request->code.' '.$request->phone
```

After check if `$phone` are exists in database

I want to use this method:

```
>  $validator->sometimes('phone', 'required|alpha_dash|max:25', function
> ($input) {
>             if ((Auth::user()->phone == $input->phone)) {
>                 return false;
> 
>             } else {
> 
>                 $t = User::where("phone", $input->phone)->get();
>                 return ($t->count() > 0) ? false : false;
> 
>             }
>         });
```

It does not work under all conditions `(True, False)` inside.

I added new validation `nickname_unique`:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'code' => 'required|string|min:3|max:4',
            'phone' => 'required|phone_unique',
            'timezone' => 'required|numeric',
            'country' => 'required|integer',
            'nickname' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:25',
            'agreement' => 'accepted'
        ], [
            'phone_unique' => 'Phone already exists!',
            'nickname_unique' => 'Nickname is busy!',
        ]);
```

It does not work, even not call validation rule below previos:

```
Validator::extend('nickname_unique', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

            dd("Here");

});
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit, which type of validation you need?

Comment: I have two incoming parameters: `code` and `phone`. I need validate both in one validation function and do request to DB to compare code, phone with existing field in db

Comment: I've posted the answer, please have a look!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define your custom validator inside `AppServiceProvider` like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('phone_unique', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
          $inputs = $validator->getData();
          $code = $inputs['code'];
          $phone = $inputs['phone'];
          $concatenated_number = $code . ' ' . $phone;
          $except_id = (!empty($parameters)) ? head($parameters) : null;

          $query = User::where('phone', $concatenated_number);
          if(!empty($except_id)) {
            $query->where('id', '<>', $except);
          }

          return $query->exists();
      });

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

> You can get all the inputs passed to the validator, by accessing `$validator` property - `getData()`

You can just add an extra parameter to your rules array after your custom validation rule (just after the `colon`) like this:

```
'phone' => 'required|phone_unique:1',
```

> Pass the `id` to be ignored while checking entries into the db

The custom validator Closure receives four arguments: the name of the `$attribute` being validated, the `$value` of the attribute, an array of `$parameters` passed to the rule, and the Validator instance.

Now you can call the validator like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'code' => 'required|string|min:3|max:4',
      'phone' => 'required|phone_unique:1',
      'timezone' => 'required|numeric',
      'country' => 'required|integer',
      'agreement' => 'accepted'
  ], [
    'phone_unique' => 'Phone already exists!', // <---- pass a message for your custom validator
  ]);
```

See more about [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: Thnaks, but last part of your answer is not clear for me

Comment: The last part just explains, how to use the validator, let me format a code a bit for you again!

Comment: I tried validation: `$validator->sometimes('nickname', 'required|alpha_dash|max:25', function ($input) {}` But it works not stable

Comment: From where did you get this, I didn't understand, this is not what you've asked, is it so?

Comment: When should work `phone_unique` wrong  validation? When function returns false?

Comment: Problem is that when I do valiudation to unique phone, I can not update my own phone, system says that this phone already is exist.

Comment: @dsfsddfsdfsf - See my updated answer! You can just add extra params to the custom rule, check the answer for solution

Comment: It works, now I added new validation rule: ` $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'code' => 'required|string|min:3|max:4',
            'phone' => 'required|phone_unique',
            'timezone' => 'required|numeric',
            'country' => 'required|integer',
            'nickname' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:25',
            'agreement' => 'accepted'
        ], [
            'phone_unique' => 'Phone already exists!',
            'nickname_unique' => 'Nickname is busy!',
        ]);`

Comment: @dsfsddfsdfsf - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: I updated question again, last time. And after will accept your asswer

Comment: @dsfsddfsdfsf - I didn't get you, can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 5):

I am writing this answer because I believe bunch of people are looking for some good answer for this topic. So I decided to share my code that I am using for booking site, where I want to check that IS NOT arrival_date > departure_date.

My `Laravel` version is `5.3.30`

```
public function postSolitudeStepTwo(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'arrival_date' => 'required|date',
        'departure_date' => 'required|departure_date_check',
        'occasional_accompaniment_requested' => 'required|integer',
        'accommodation' => 'required|integer',
        'are_you_visiting_director' => 'required|integer',
    ];

    if ($request->input('are_you_visiting_director') == 1) {
        $rules['time_in_lieu'] = 'required|integer';
    }

    $messages = [
        'departure_date_check' => 'Departure date can\'t be smaller then Arrival date.Please check your dates.'
    ];

    $validation = validator(
        $request->toArray(),
        $rules,
        $messages
    );

    //If validation fail send back the Input with errors
    if($validation->fails()) {
        //withInput keep the users info
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages());
    } else {
        MySession::setSessionData('arrival_date', $request);
        MySession::setSessionData('departure_date', $request);
        MySession::setSessionData('occasional_accompaniment_requested', $request);
        MySession::setSessionData('accommodation', $request);
        MySession::setSessionData('are_you_visiting_director', $request);
        MySession::setSessionData('time_in_lieu', $request);
        MySession::setSessionData('comment_solitude_step2_1', $request);

        //return $request->session()->all();
        return redirect("/getSolitudeStepThree");
    }
}
```

My controller is **StepController** and there I have declared a method as you can see called postSolitudeStepTwo. I declare the rules and on departure date notice that for the rule we have `required|departure_date_check`. That will be the name of the method in

```
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

The code there looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('departure_date_check', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $inputs = $validator->getData();
        $arrivalDate = $inputs['arrival_date'];
        $departureDate = $inputs['departure_date'];
        $result = true;
        if ($arrivalDate > $departureDate) {
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    });
}
```

As the [Laravel documentation 5.3 Custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) we need to extend the Validator facade, the signature of that method has to be:

```
Validator::extend(name_of_the_function, function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
```

And I believe the rest is clear.

Hope it will help somebody.

[image: Cutom Validation error frontend]

Answer (score 2):

```
$messsages = array(
        'email.required'=>'Email is Required',
        'phone.required'=>'Phone number is Required',

    );

    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',

    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules,$messsages);



    if ($validator->fails()):
        $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
    endif;
```

Comment: In your case why not to use something like:
`'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:arrival_date'`  ?